# i can't install mysqlclient and pillow in python

Tags: python, django, linux

i want to install mysqlclient but it returns me

```
(venv)amir@amg76:~/Documents/Computer/Python/Django/vira/virasciencecom$ pip3 install mysqlclient==1.3.7
Collecting mysqlclient==1.3.7
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.7.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-c5i8m5ok/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-c5i8m5ok/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/tmp/pip-build-c5i8m5ok/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-c5i8m5ok/mysqlclient/
```

the same thing happen when i try to install pillow and i use python 3.6 and ubuntu 17.10
can any body help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `libmysqlclient-dev` or `libmariaclient-dev` from your distro package repository, depending whether you're using mysql or mariadb respectively.